# C++ if/else confusion

Tags: c++, class, if-statement

This is my code which which checks if **numOfAcc** (Variable) is less than 10 or equal to 0. Which then continues on with the code that I have provided if true.

```
void customer::add_account()
{
    int selec;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(numOfAcc<10 || numOfAcc == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n\nTo enter new account for this customer enter 1";
            cout << "\nTo go back please enter 0" << endl;
            cin >> selec;
            switch(selec)
            {
            case 0:
                officer_func();
                break;
            case 1:
                bankAccount acc;
                acc.getAccountDetails();
                accs[numOfAcc]=acc;
                numOfAcc++;
                break;
                //b.getAccountDetails(); c.numOfAcc++; break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"MAXIMUM ACCOUNTS LIMIT REACHED"<<endl;
            cout << c.numOfAcc; //test code to check the value of numOfAcc which returns as ZERO
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

I have previously initialized numOfAcc member (which belongs to a class) as ZERO in another function. But it always ends up with the else statement "MAXIMUM ACCOUNTS LIMIT REACHED" when in run mode.

**I checked if the numOfAcc member is zero or not with a cout statement, and it returns as zero. There's a problem with the if/else statments**

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Nope if its equal to 10, I do not allow any more accounts to be created. Still doesn't solve it, mate. Ends up in the else statement

Comment: My problem is, even when numOfAcc is zero or less than 10.. it ends up in else .... whaaaat :/

Comment: @user2425207 Can you provide a [complete and compilable](http://sscce.org) sample which reproduces the issue?

Comment: what is `c.numOfAcc` ?

Comment: have you initialized or define `numOfAcc` somewhere else anyway?

Comment: @user2425207 As Sander said, you are (most likely) using two different variables for the `if()` and the `cout`.

Comment: Its Customer c, object. numofAcc is a count which keeps track of the number of accounts opened. In this case, even when the count is 0 or less than 10.. it ends up in else

Comment: @user2425207 : but `c` is presumably not the same object as `*this` ... which would make `c.numOfAcc` different from `numOfAcc` (or `this->numOfAcc`).

Comment: @user2425207: Are you sure that `numOfAcc` (that's `this->numOfAcc`, not `c.numOfAcc`, unless `c` is a reference to this object) has been initialised to a sensible value before this function? Could you include the `cout` statement you used to check that? Or are you referring to the one in the code, which prints the member of a different object?

Comment: You must be initializing `::numOfAcc`, not `customer::numOfAcc` by error. Or, a different customer. If `numOfAcc` (that is, `customer::numOfAcc`) is zero, there is no way it could go into the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

First, in `if (numOfAcc<10 || numOfAcc == 0)` the second part is not needed, because if numOfAcc is 0, it will be already <10.

Second, if you are sure that numOfAcc is 0 and that there is a problem with your "if" statement, since you enter "else" with a value of 0 nomOfAcc, you can write the following:

```
if (numOfAcc<10 || numOfAcc == 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    assert(numOfAcc != 0); // assert what "should be true"
    cout << ...
}
```

Then run a Debug build of your code. One of these two things will happen:

- **If the assert fails:** You are right. At some point you enter the else branch with numOfAcc == 0. What you say in your question is true.
- **If the assert does *not* fail:** You are wrong. You never enter the else branch with numOfAcc == 0. What you say in your question is wrong.

Note that of these two possible outcomes, the first one is impossible.

What happens when you do this test?

Answer (score 0):

You have short circuiting issues in your code (As @MikeSeymour said -- this will not cause any issues as of now, but something to fix before it hurts)

```
if(numOfAcc<10 || numOfAcc == 0)
```

`numOfAcc == 0` will only be evaluated if `numOfAcc <10`, i.e. the second condition is evaluated only if the first condition is false.  Otherwise the `if`-condition is true and the second condition need not be evaluated, since `true || false == true`, so the evaluation of the second condition does not mater.

So you should have separate checks, since if a number is 0, it always less than 10, and thus the condition will always be true.

This link may be useful for you -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

In your else part you have `c.numOfAcc`  But in the checks you use `numOfAcc`. Why is this inconsistent? May be you should be using `if(c.numOfAcc<10 || c.numOfAcc == 0)`

Comment: This does not answer the question. The second check is redundant, but it won't cause any problems.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes, agreed. I have updated the answer with one probable reason for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numOfAcc == 0)
{
}
else
{
    cout << c.numOfAcc;
}
```

This could only print zero because `numOfAcc` and `c.numOfAcc` are two different things.

There is nothing wrong with `if...else` statements.

There are other things wrong with your code which the other answers have explained.